# What are the functional differences between all the versions of Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

I subscribe to Adobe's Lightroom/photoshop combo and have recently found 3 versions of Lightroom on my PC:

1. Adobe Lightroom classic CC
2. Adobe Lightroom CC
3. Adobe Lightroom

I understand that Lightroom CC is the multi-platform offering. it's great! but doesn't seem to have the extensive features of the normal version.

I can't tell the different between `Adobe Lightroom classic` and `Adobe Lightroom`

Which version do I use and why have I got 2 seemingly classic versions that point to different catalogs...

Comment: You didn't mention Mac or PC, but on the PC go to Help Menu->About Lightroom ... and it will show something like "7.0 Release". On the Mac use the App Menu. Compare these three and should give an indication of what is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the 'photography' plan offers Lightroom CC and Lightroom Classic CC.

They recently renamed the 'old' Lightroom to Lightroom Classic CC.
This means that on your computer there is probably an old executable.
As answered By Alex you can just open a different (correct) catalog and you will probably not be able to tell the difference at all.

My advice is to start only using Lightroom Classic CC as this one is currently maintained by your creative cloud app.

Lightroom CC is the new version of Lightroom that just got out of beta.
While it has a large cloud component you can still use it just on your local computer.
In my experience Lightroom CC still lacks a few features from Lightroom Classic CC (that might not make it back at all).
But it adds syncing to the Adobe's Creative Cloud and gives you the ability to edit your pictures on any device you have.
And that also means you have another backup location.

Source:

https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/plans.html
http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom.html

Answer (score 1):

*Adobe Photoshop Lightroom CC* is a cloud-based service with desktop and mobile applications and cloud storage.

*Adobe Photoshop Lightroom Classic CC* is a standalone desktop application earlier known as *Adobe Photoshop Lightroom*.

> I can't tell the different between Adobe Lightroom classic and Adobe Lightroom

It's generally the same product, but Classic CC is a newer version and you have to subscribe for a monthly plan in order to use its editing functions.

---

> I got 2 seemingly classic versions that point to different catalogs...

Lightroom does not "point" to any catalog. It opens a catalog and works with it. Open another catalog and it will "point" to that.